# SunOne webMail - mail rule format

Tags: webmail, rules, sun-one

Migrating eMails off a SunOne mail server. Getting the messages (via POP3) is easy. But I also want to grab the mail rules users have configured. I don't seem to be able to find documentation about them. What format are they stored in?